# await Task returns WaitingForActivation?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a consumer/producer set-up sharing a BlockingCollection.

```
public void StartConsumer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
     {               

         foreach (var value in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken))
         {
             var rowsAffected = await  GetFooAsync(value.Id);                     
         }                

     }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current)
     .ContinueWith(task => HandleConsumerStopped(task, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
}
```

The task returned from the first thread to the 'ContinueWith' has always a result of a Task. 
and that task has a result of 'WaitingForActivation',

So,my question is, Why is it coming out of the foreach loop? 
should it not block until the cancellationToken is cancelled?

is the iner GetFooAsync causing some behaviour to break from the Foreach??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current code will call `HandleConsumerStopped` as soon as it hits the first `await`, because that's when your async method returns to the caller. Notice that your StartNew is returning a `Task<Task>` you need to attach continuation for the inner task. Currently your code attaches it for the outer task.

If you want to complete for the whole asynchronous method to complete you can simply call the `HandleConsumerStopped` method inside the async method itself.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
 { 
     foreach (var value in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken))
     {
         var rowsAffected = await  GetFooAsync(value.Id);                     
     }

     HandleConsumerStopped();//Parameters removed
 }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);
```

If you're constrained to using `ContinueWith` then you need to use `Task.Run` or you need to call `Unwrap`. If you use `Task.Run` you get the `UnWrap` for free but no `TaskCreationOptions` flags.

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
 {          
     foreach (var value in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(cancellationToken))
     {
         var rowsAffected = await GetFooAsync(value.Id);                     
     }                

 }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current)
 .UnWrap()//Note the unwrap here
 .ContinueWith(task => HandleConsumerStopped(task, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
```

Now `HandleConsumerStopped` will be run once the whole body of the `StartNew` is completed, not in the middle of `foreach`.